# Best way to fix security problems caused by windows updates?

Tags: security, windows-registry, windows-update

I have a laptop running Windows 7 32-bit.

Last nights security updates caused my logitech mouse to stop working (specifically, it caused several USB ports to stop altogether).  After reviewing the system event log I found that the IPBusEnum component was failing due to an activation security error.

A little more research and I found that this was caused by the TrustedInstaller replacing the security permissions on those keys and generally mucking them up.  To fix this I had to open regedit, take ownership of ALL the keys related to IPBusEnum and force it to use the inherited permissions from the tree.

Is there a better way to fix this when MS screws up the updates?  I would hate to have to walk around to a number of machines and manually fix the registry key security settings.

Comment: For future reference, you could check the Windows Update Downloader (http://www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com/) before applying an update to see if it is going to cause any issues.

Comment: @ Synetech, how does this let you check for issues when all it does is download updates?

Comment: @ Chris Lively, I would like to know how you troubleshot this issue and found it was caused by TI, and what was the event log ID, thanks

Comment: @Moab: this happened over 2 months ago.. ;)  I'll see if the logs still exist for that time.  In a nutshell, I tried a different USB mouse and it failed to work as well.  Then I went through the event log and found numerous logs around the IPBusEnum item.  I tracked down the error codes it was throwing which indicated a security problem.  I then went to the appropriate registry keys and saw that the TrustedInstaller had replaced permissions on that branch.  So, I removed those and reinherited the permissions.  After that IPBusEnum started working, as well as my mouse.

Comment: Thanks Chris Lively, it always good to know USB issues and fixes, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I bet it was event ID 10016...http://www.vistax64.com/crashes-debugging/283591-event-id-10016-related-ipbusenum.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.  There is no real way to fix these types of issues.  It's happened again since my original post on the subject and the general feeling is that you simply have to fix one machine while making sure every step taken is written down.  Then script it for deployment to the enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

powershell lets you perform registry operations from scripts/command-line

Answer (score 0):

System Restore usually does the trick by reverting the computer and its updates. To find out which update is screwing you up, well, that's a different story.